# Properly rendering Rails partial on collection of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have two Model/Controllers which are essentially duplicating data (just on different pages).  When I iterate through a collection on one of the controllers, it works just as intended, however when I run the collection through the partial on the other controller, it creates another "object"

```
def show (users_controller.rb)
  ...
  @missions = @user.missions
  @mission = current_user.missions.build
  ...
end


def index (missions_controller.rb)
  ...
  @missions = @user.missions
  @mission = current_user.missions.build
  ...
end
```

When I call `render @missions` (app/views/missions/_mission.html.erb) on both the `show.html.erb` and `index.html.erb` files.  It works as intended on the `Users_controller` but creates an extra "object" on the `Missions_controller`.  It seems to be rendering both the `@mission` and `@missions` variables in the controller when rendering the collection.

Why and how can I fix this?  I've tried moving the partial to a shared view directory, but the problem remains.  I'm assuming it has to do with how I named my instance variables?  I'm super stumped.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I would say this is likely happening because the mission you're building is included in @user.missions. Criteria aren't evaluated until they're actually used (by calling .all or .each or something) so by using current_user.missions.build you're adding an empty mission to the end of @user.missions... assuming that current_user and @user are the same.

So you can probably fix this by changing the call to `@missions = @user.missions.all` which will force it to be evaluated immediately, before the built mission is added to the end.

As I said, just a guess though!

Comment: wow, that worked like a charm!  im still not sure why though.  Hm.  Does it have something to do with the fact that the call `@missions` is coming from the missions_controller?  I'm confused on why a call to this collection would include the variable `@mission` as well...

Comment: So user.missions does not actually evaluate until it's used; it returns an association proxy that is evaluated only after a method that requires its data is called on it. So when you say @user.missions, you're saying, "At some future point but not now, give me all the missions associated with this user." Then immediately afterwards you're building a new association for that user. When you actually use missions, it executes the query and returns all the missions for that user, INCLUDING the one you just built. Calling .all immediately returns only the missions already saved and built.

Comment: thanks...its making a bit more sense.  curious as to why it works as intended on one controller but not on the other?  shouldn't it execute the same on both?